# Encrypting a txt file using Caesar cipher

Tags: java, arrays, encryption

I am working on a project where it is required to encrypt a `.txt` file. I am pretty new to programming so my code is faulty. I don't know how to convert the text in the file to a `char` variable to add the left-shift of 4.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class CaesarCipher {
    
    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        
        File file = new File ("data_plain_alphabet.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
        
        }
        
        
        scan.close();
    }

    public static String caesar(String line) {
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++ ) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            char[] chars = line.toCharArray();
            
            System.out.print(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Other than the spurious `String line = scan.nextLine();` (which currently should not compile) you have successfully converted to a `char` array, right? So you now just need to retrieve the values from the array.

Answer (score -1):

Since you managed to read from the file, what's left is to cipher the alphabet text.
You can do something like this:

```
 String cipher(String message, int offset) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    offset = offset % 26;

    for (char character : message.toCharArray()) {
        if (character != ' ') {
            int originalAlphabetPosition = character - 'a';
            int newAlphabetPosition = (originalAlphabetPosition + offset) % 26;
            if (newAlphabetPosition < 0) {
                newAlphabetPosition = 26 + newAlphabetPosition;
            }
            char newCharacter = (char) ('a' + newAlphabetPosition);
            result.append(newCharacter);
        } else {
            result.append(character);
        }
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Taken from - [Caesar Cipher in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-caesar-cipher)

So you can call a method like this for each line in the file:

```
String cipheredLine = cipher(line, -4);
```

Output examples:

- cipher("a", 4); // "e"
- cihper("a", -4); // "w"
- cipher("z", 4); // "d"
- cipher("z", -4); // "v"
- cipher("a", 30) // "e"

If you are required to update the file, you can write the ciphered text to a temporary file, then once you are done iterating over the file, delete it and rename the temporary file to the original's name.

Comment: Won't that code fail if line is "a" in the call you make?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes You are correct, sorry. Fixed my answer and added output examples.